# Table buttons over fixed toolbar

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a problem when more data is in a table an I have to scroll the data, the data gets scrolled, but the buttons from a table go over the top of the fixed toolbar.

Here is the example code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ocrvtg

How can I fix that?

Comment: `mat-toolbar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
}` will correct your issue (but not the poor design)

Comment: But, if you click on Items per page select field, the options go under the toolbar.

Comment: Your code looks fine, what issue you exactly facing? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z-index has default value 0, So if you set z-index for your toolbar to 1 and for table to no z-index(or 0). It will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [sticky positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). Not supported in IE11, but it should degrade gracefully.

```
.toolbar--sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
}
```

---

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="toolbar--sticky">
```